# Loop through array of objects and return accumulated data from those objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

So I have an array that comes from my database. An array has an object inside. I have hours and employee id as well as a list of employees on the web page. When I click on employee I want to see that number of hours that assigned to that employee.

```
var makeup_hrs = api_resp.makeup_data[key];

for (var i = 0; i < makeup_hrs.length; i++) {
  var obj = makeup_hrs[i];
  console.log(obj);
  for (var o in obj) {
    var y = obj[o];
    console.log("make up hours ", y, "id: ", emp_id)

    var x = document.getElementById("makeUpHours").innerHTML = y;
    console.log(x);

    // $('#makeUpHours').html(y);
  }
}
```

Anytime I print make up hours and emp_id - it gives me the number of that employee and his hours value. But when I innerHTML it only shows the last hours value , not a specific hour to a specific employee.

like that(console output) I have only 2 employees for now in my database:

```
 make up hours  4 id:  2891
make up hours  7 id:  1978
```

here is my html (it is inside of the modal - bootstrap)

```
<div class="form-group">   <label class="col-sm-3"> Hours </label> 
  &nbsp;<span id="makeUpHours"></span></div>
```

when I click on the icon - modal pops up . Every icon is assigned to an employee id

[image]

[image]

[image]

Employee id comes from a one array and hours from another one. Somehow when I console log 2 values together they assign the right id number to the right hour number.

Comment: can you provide a mock of the data you are working with?

Comment: Could you also provide a trimmed down version of your HTML. You said it only shows the last hours which makes sense since your for loop is saving the y value in the same HTML element (`#makeUpHours`).

Comment: Provide us a sample of your data nicely formatted

Comment: Sounds like a job for Array.reduce(). But we need to know the structure of the source data indeed.

Comment: @Shilly it's not, the problem is that the OP is just overriding the data in the same DOM element for each index of the loop

Comment: @AyushGupta Hence if you reduce the data into one html string, you can keep one call to `.innerHTML()` at the end,so you keep DOM performance. While at the same time not overwriting the innerHTML every time.

Comment: @Shilly yes I agree. To be clear, I am not saying that Array.reduce will not be useful, but rather, that the OPs problems seems to be something other than extraction of the values.

Comment: I assume that I need to loop through the emp_id and assign to each one their hour, using innerHtml

Comment: @Dennys is the data historical data(i.e. wont change for a particular date), or it can change on the backend for the same query parameters?

Comment: @AyushGupta, Sorry, I misunderstood then what you meant. @Dennys. You replace the contents of the innerHTML every time instead of adding extra html to it. So the solution might be as simple as just using `.innerHTML += y;`, but we can't know that for sure without knowing how `makeup_hrs` looks like. Since you are using `for ( var o in obj )` for some reason, I want to avoid just posting an answer without being able to test if it'll work.

Comment: @AyushGupta its is database, which I manually created. I have 2 employees there for now. I edited my post - you can see 2 output in console - id and their hour number.

Comment: Please  post a mockup for it. For example: `var makeup_hrs = [{ "id" : 2891, "hours" : 4, "name" : "john doe" },{ "id" :1978, "hours" : 7, "name" : "jane doe" }];`

Comment: @AyushGupta += works like that : it assign value of 47 (these 2 values that i have 4 and 7, just put them together) for both employees

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `innerHTML` on every iteration rather than adding to it (so only the last iteration will be shown).

Here's a sample solution:

```js
// sample data
const employees = [{
  name: 'Bob',
  hours: 10
}, {
  name: 'Jane',
  hours: 15
}, {
  name: 'John',
  hours: 20
}]

const ul = document.getElementById('employees')

// how you want to represent an employee's info
const stringifyData = employee => `${employee.name}: ${employee.hours} hours`

// add employee HTML 
const addEmployee = str => {
  ul.innerHTML += `<li>${str}</li>`
}

// iterate
employees.map(stringifyData).forEach(addEmployee)
```

```html
<ul id="employees"></ul>
```

I prefer to separate data transformations from DOM manipulations (easier to test) but you could of course do both in one iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do some theoretical stuff to understand the problem better, for understanding an underlying problem is key to finding a solution.

So imagine that you have an array of objects:

```
[{
  id: 1,
  x: 10,
}, {
  id: 2,
  x: 20,
}, {
  id: 3,
  x: 30,
}];
```

and as a result, you want this HTML markup to put into `innerHTML` property of an arbitrary DOM element:

```
<p>id: 1, x: 10</p>
<p>id: 2, x: 20</p>
<p>id: 3, x: 30</p>
```

(mind absence of a single common parent, which is valid for innerHTML)

You could go through an array of objects with a `for` loop, then through properties of each object with another `for` loop pretty much as you did, with only remark that you need to *accumulate result* somewhere outside of scope of any of those loops, but preferably in scope of the function that will change `innerHTML` of a target element. Something like this:

```
let result = '';

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  result += `<p>id: ${array[i].id}, x: ${array[i].x}</p>`;
}

element.innerHTML = result;
```

but more suitable in your case.

Using `for` loops brings us to a practice widely followed in Javascript community these days: applying map and reduce (see [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)) to a collection of similarly typed elements. With this approach, the code would look like:

```
element.innerHTML = array.reduce((total, current) => `${total}<p>id: ${current.id}, x: ${current.x}</p>`, '');
```

which may look a bit convoluted, but gives exactly the same effect.

And remember: if you want to *add* something to a string (namely, concatenate), use `+=`; if you want to *replace* its value, use `=`.